How to prevent Goto Line (Ctrl + G) from jumping while typing in VSCode?
The default behaviour of Goto Line will jump when I am typing, which is not very useful to me, as the content in Line 1, Line 12 and Line 123 are probably not related to each other. If I want to go to Line 123 from Line 100, the cursor will move to Line 1 first, which makes me lose the sight on my target line.
I tried searching in settings with "Goto", but I did not find any option related to "Goto Line", is there a way to change this default behaviour?

No way to do that. Simply type it quickly. Not sure what the goal of seeing the current line while typing slowly is.
